# Rails is using fixtures without my permission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, fixtures

I've started with a simple test:

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'should not create user without email' do
    user = User.new
    assert_not user.save
  end
end
```

And Rails auto-generated some fixtures:

```
one:
  email: MyString
  login_token: MyString
  token_generated_at: 2017-09-10 17:24:55

two:
  email: MyString
  login_token: MyString
  token_generated_at: 2017-09-10 17:24:55
```

So as you can see I didn't use any fixtures for my test. But when executing the test, Rails throws an exception:

```
Error:
UserTest#test_should_not_create_user_without_email:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "login_token", "token_date", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyString', 'MyString', '2017-09-10 17:24:55', '2017-09-10 15:48:11.483364', '2017-09-10 15:48:11.483364', 298486374)
```

At first I thougt I could simply delete the fixtures. But later there should be fixtures with for example non-unique email.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load fixtures Rails don't need your permissions. From the [documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html#class-ActiveRecord::FixtureSet-label-Using+Fixtures+in+Test+Cases):

> The testing environment **will automatically** load all the fixtures into
>   the database before each test. To ensure consistent data, the
>   environment deletes the fixtures before running the load.